# ASP.NET MVC5 Custom Attribute losing local property value in GetClientValidationRules()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-attributes

I have this custom attribute that was working some time ago:

```
// This checks to see if the question is mandatory and needs a answer
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CheckMandatoryAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public bool IsMandatory { get; private set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        bool isMandatory = (bool)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("IsMandatory").GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        this.IsMandatory = isMandatory;

        if (isMandatory && value == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success; ;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "checkmandatory"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("ismandatory", IsMandatory);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

I'm 100% sure that it used to work.
The problem is now that when GetClientValidationRules() is called, the IsMandatory boolean is always false, even though it gets set as true when the IsValid() method is called before hand.

[image: The boolean gets set correctly]

Here is how the custom attribute is being used:

```
public class ConductQuestionAnswerViewModel : BaseModel
{       
    public bool IsMandatory { get; set; }

    [CheckMandatory(ErrorMessage = "Your response is mandatory.")]
    [CheckEval(ErrorMessage = "You need to make an evaluation for your response.")]
    [UIHint("Radio")]
    public int? YourResponse { get; set; }
}
```

The IsValid() method is returning the correct value, so server-side validation is working.
However, as the GetClientValidationRules() is not working, the incorrect value is being set on the property data attribute. Therefore, the client-side validation is not working.

[image: Custom validation data attribute]

Comment: You are 100% that when you debug on the GetClientValidationRules, IsMandatory is False? This is a total long shot as i cant see anything wrong with your code, but try changing the rule.ValidationParameters.Add() to take a string representation for IsMandatory. So it would be rule.ValidationParameters.Add("ismandatory", "true");

Comment: Yes. It's definitely false. If I set the value to true as you suggested the client-side validation works. But only certain questions are mandatory. Hence, I'm still stuck

Comment: `GetClientValidationRules()` is called internally by the HtmlHelper class to generate the `data-val-*` attributes when generating the html in the view. `IsValid()` is called when you post the data. They are 2 completely different thing. You dont pass a value of a property to `ValidationParameters.Add()` - you pass the name of the property you want to compare against (in your case it would be  `ValidationParameters.Add("CheckMandatory", "IsMandatory")`

Comment: Then you write the jquery methods in a script to add the rules using `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add()` and `$.validator.addMethod()` which gets the value of the property `IsMandatory` in the view (I assume its a checkbox) and make the comparison